# Pandas apply InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,0] = -1 is not in [0, 9725) with a keras model

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I have a Keras model that takes `userId`, `movieId` and `genre` as input

```
def RecModel(n_latent_factors_user, n_latent_factors_movie, n_latent_factors_genre) :
    genre_input = keras.Input(shape=[1],name='genre')
    genre_embedding = layers.Embedding(n_movies + 1, n_latent_factors_genre, name='genre-Embedding')(genre_input)
    genre_vec = layers.Flatten(name='Flattengenre')(genre_embedding)
    genre_vec = layers.Dropout(0.2)(genre_vec)

    movie_input = keras.Input(shape=[1],name='Item')
    movie_embedding = layers.Embedding(n_movies + 1, n_latent_factors_movie, name='Movie-Embedding')(movie_input)
    movie_vec = layers.Flatten(name='FlattenMovies')(movie_embedding)
    movie_vec = layers.Dropout(0.2)(movie_vec)


    user_input = keras.Input(shape=[1],name='User')
    user_vec = layers.Flatten(name='FlattenUsers')(keras.layers.Embedding(n_users + 1, n_latent_factors_user,name='User-Embedding')(user_input))
    user_vec = layers.Dropout(0.2)(user_vec)

    concat = layers.concatenate([genre_vec, user_vec, movie_vec], axis=1)
    concat_dropout = layers.Dropout(0.2)(concat)
    dense = layers.Dense(100,name='FullyConnected')(concat)
    dropout_1 = layers.Dropout(0.2,name='Dropout')(dense)
    dense_2 = layers.Dense(50,name='FullyConnected-1')(concat)
    dropout_2 = layers.Dropout(0.2,name='Dropout')(dense_2)
    dense_3 = layers.Dense(20,name='FullyConnected-2')(dense_2)
    dropout_3 = layers.Dropout(0.2,name='Dropout')(dense_3)
    dense_4 = layers.Dense(10,name='FullyConnected-3', activation='relu')(dense_3)


    result = layers.Dense(1, activation='relu',name='Activation')(dense_4)
    adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.005)
    model = keras.Model([user_input, movie_input, genre_input], result)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam,loss= 'mean_absolute_error')
    return model
```

I can do a simple 1 line prediction and it is all fine

```
model.predict([np.array([200-1]), np.array([10-1]), np.array([705])])[0][0]
```

outputs `3.8064451`

Now I want to generate this prediction for all the movieIds that a specific user reviewed. I did it as follows

```
newratedmovies.head()

    userId  movieId rating  title   genres
0   0   0   4.0 Toy Story (1995)    351
1   4   0   4.0 Toy Story (1995)    351
2   6   0   4.5 Toy Story (1995)    351
3   14  0   2.5 Toy Story (1995)    351
4   16  0   4.5 Toy Story (1995)    351
```

````
user_ratings = newratedmovies[newratedmovies['userId'] == TESTUSER][['userId', 'movieId', 'rating', 'genres']]```

    user_ratings['prediction'] = user_ratings.apply(lambda x: predict_rating(TESTUSER, x['movieId'], x['genres']), axis=1)
    user_ratings.sort_values(by='rating', 
                             ascending=False).merge(movies, 
                                                    on='movieId', 
                                                    how='inner', 
                                                    suffixes=['_u', '_m']).head(20)
````

With the line `user_ratings.apply` above, I am getting error

```
InvalidArgumentError:  indices[0,0] = -1 is not in [0, 9725)
     [[node model_1/Movie-Embedding/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-25-d80ad7273868>:8) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_18819]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node model_1/Movie-Embedding/embedding_lookup:
 model_1/Movie-Embedding/embedding_lookup/18764 (defined at /Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:81)

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

Not sure what it means. Any mismatch with the model architecture? Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: why movieId and userId have negative values (-1 for example) ?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani what makes you think that is the case here? Are you saying this because of the error message ```indices[0,0] = -1```

Comment: I think so... did you check?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani got it, actually the model is fine but when predicting through the `predict` function I did ```model.predict([np.array([user_id-1]), np.array([movie_id-1]), np.array([genre])])[0][0]``` which is stupid. Updated it to ```model.predict([np.array([user_id]), np.array([movie_id]), np.array([genre])])[0][0]``` and it works